# PInvoke DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I want to pass a structure to C function and I write the following code.

When I run it, the first function - `Foo1` is working and then function `Foo` gets an exception. Can you help me to understand what the problem is?...

The C code:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int Size; 
    //char *Array;
}TTest;

__declspec(dllexport) void Foo(void  *Test);
__declspec(dllexport) int  Foo1();

void Foo(void  *Test)
{
    TTest *X = (TTest *)Test;
    int i = X->Size;
    /*for(int i=0;i<Test->Size;Test++)
    {
        Test->Array[i] = 127;
    }*/
}

int Foo1()
{
    return 10;
}
```

The C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class TTest 
    {
        public int Size; 
    }

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"C:\.net course\unmanaged1\unmanaged3\Debug\unmanaged3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern void Foo(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
            TTest lplf   // characteristics
        );

        [DllImport(@"C:\.net course\unmanaged1\unmanaged3\Debug\unmanaged3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int Foo1();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TTest Test = new TTest();
            Test.Size = 25;

            int XX = Program.Foo1();
            Program.Foo(Test);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]` and add `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` to both of your `DllImport`s and it should be fine.

Comment: please add exception details to your question, and any other info that could help people answer it

Answer (score 7):

**To the downvoters**: This answer solves two issues: the immediate issue of the calling convention/the `MarhsalAs` attribute, and the issue he will soon find where his `TTest` parameter won't work if he takes my suggestion of turning `TTest` into a struct.

Your native code is asking for a `void*`, which in C# is an `IntPtr`. First you should define `TTest` as a struct and not a class. Second, you should change the declaration of `Foo` to:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\.net course\unmanaged1\unmanaged3\Debug\unmanaged3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Foo(IntPtr lplf);
```

And third, you should pin the `TTest` using the `fixed` keyword and pass it's pointer to `Foo`. If you're using a class, you can use `Marhsal.StructureToPtr` to get an `IntPtr` from your `TTest`.

This provides the same functionality on both sides, where a pointer to any type can be passed in. You can also write overloads with all the class types that you want to use since they all equate to `void*` on the native side. With a struct, your parameters would be prepended with a `ref`.

What I'm curious about is why your native code wants a `void*` instead of a `TTest*` when the first thing you do in the unmanaged code is cast to a `TTest*`. If you switched the parameter to a `TTest*`, then providing identical functionality becomes simpler. You declaration would become:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\.net course\unmanaged1\unmanaged3\Debug\unmanaged3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Foo(ref TTest lplf);
```

And you would call the function as `Program.Foo(ref Test);`

If you're using the class, the `ref` isn't necessary as classes are reference types.

Comment: -1 All of these changes are completely unnecessary and still fail to address the actual error the OP is getting (stack imbalance is my guess).

Comment: @ildjarn I added the CallingConvention and removed the MarshalAs attribute as part of my answer. That will solve the immediate issue. After the error gets fixed, he would hit another error where his `TTest` parameter wouldn't work as a `void*`.

Comment: "*After the error gets fixed, he would hit another error where his `TTest` parameter wouldn't work as a `void*`.*" No he wouldn't -- to C#, `TTest*` and `void*` are 100% identical (as `TTest` is _currently_ defined).

Comment: Getting rid of the `MarhsalAs` attribute turns it into a regular `TTest` and not a `TTest*`

Comment: `TTest` is a class, so it is _implicitly_ passed by reference. What you said would be true only if `TTest` were a struct (which it shouldn't be).

Comment: And that's where the discrepancy is, I suggested turning `TTest` into a struct.

Comment: Which, again, is completely unnecessary. ;-]

Comment: Well, we can't see the rest of his code, but it would simplify things if he's passing a `TTest` by value a lot (omit the `ref` instead of adding a `[Out, In]`). If he's always passing by reference, then yes, making it a struct is unnecessary and useless.

Comment: And even with struct, I believe, you can sill use `ref Test` instead of `IntPtr`. Because, .NET will make `TTest*` out of it - and it is C++ (not C#) to whom it is 100% identical whether it receives `Test*` or `void*` as an arg.

Comment: Edited my answer to be more specific about the difference between classes and structs.

Comment: So i change the code to use with TTest instead of void * and it is working but i gets massage box that tell me:

Additional Information: A call to PInvoke function 'ConsoleApplication1!ConsoleApplication1.Program::Foo' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

is it ok??
and how i am soled this massgae\exeption.

Comment: Did you change the CallingConvention on the C# side? Did you change the C# declaration to pass in a `ref TTest` (unless you didn't change it to a struct)? On the C side, are you passing in a `TTest*` or just a `TTest`?

Comment: you are rigth i forget to change the CallingConvention

Answer (score 1):

You are using C call so you need to specify CallingConvention.Cdecl

```
[DllImport(@"C:\.net course\unmanaged1\unmanaged3\Debug\unmanaged3.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

By default its stdcall in C# pinvoke as i remember; You can also do change C code instead and leave your C# code as is like in below

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall  Foo(void  *Test);
```

But for me best is to both declare __cdecl (or stdcall) in your C export and CallingConvention.Cdecl (or stdcall) in your C# code to keep convenience. You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2017 and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.7.2 for further info