# C# Pinvoke of C Code issue

Tags: c#, pinvoke

What I am trying to do: I have some embedded C code which does some signal processing. I also have a set of C# tools. I would like to use the C# code to be call the embedded C code with some waveforms to 'test' the algorithm and see what it is thinking/doing.

What I did:

Embedded C code:

```
__declspec (dllexport) void SigInit(int Flag);   
void SigInit(int Flag) {  ... }
```

I compile as a Win32 DLL. Configuration type is "Dynamic Library (.dll)" and MFC is set to "Uses Standard Windows Libraries". I "viewed" my library in the Visual Studio 2010 Class viewer and everything looks good.

Then in my C# code (VS2010 with .NET 4.0):

```
public static class ProcessSignals
{

    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\rpease\Desktop\SigLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void SigInit(int Flag);
}
```

But whenever I try to run the main program and call ProcessSignals.SigInit(0):

Unable to find an entry point named 'SigInit' in DLL 'C:\Users\rpease\Desktop\SigLibrary.dll'.

I was thinking this was a name-mangling issue but thought I took care of that. Suggestions appreciated. I think I am following the guidelines in: [PInvoke DLL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369301/pinvoke-dll-in-c-sharp)  but can't get past this.

Thanks,

Roger

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and saying that it is using decorated naming. You can use a DLL Explorer program and check to see what the signature is.

Comment: Use Dependency Walker (for instance) to check what functions are exported by your DLL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Visual Studio command prompt and change directory to the the folder that contains the DLL in question, and then run:

```
dumpbin <nameOfDll> /exports
```

(where `<nameOfDll>` is the filename of your DLL file, without the angle brackets)

Do you then see the name of the function you are expecting listed?

Comment: Ok-- this was a good hint. I had set the export flags but for whatever reason the compiler started updating a different file. Thanks everyone these were quite helpful tips!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the c++ compiler renames functions.
Declare your exported function as

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void SigInit(int Flag);
}
```

**OR**

Use depends.exe to view the actual exported name of the function and set the `Entrypoint` in the `DllImport` attribute.

Comment: I had tried this but got this error http://support.microsoft.com/kb/133070  so I figured the compiler was compiling as C rather than C++.